# Overriding the paint method in JTextField to draw text

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jtextfield

I am wishing to draw a number onto a `JTextField` by overwriting the paint method. So that when the user edits the text field the number doesn't disappear. However, at the moment, the number isn't appearing at all, I have tried:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  
     super.paintComponent(g);
     if(number != 0){
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(number),0,0);
     }  
}
```

Any ideas, is this even possible?

Comment: `if(number != 0){`  Do something else (e.g. different color) if `number==0`!

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to play with Y position in the `g.drawString(String.valueOf(number),0,0);` call. E.g. use `getHeight()/2`

Answer (score 2):

> ..when the user edits the text field the number doesn't disappear.

As pointed out by @mKorbel, there is no need to override a `JTextField` in order to get red numbers, simply configure it using the public methods.  OTOH..

```
g.drawString(String.valueOf(number),0,0);
```

If this is really all about numbers, perhaps the best approach is to use a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html), and set a custom [`SpinnerUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/SpinnerUI.html).

Answer (score 1):

maybe there no reason override `paintComponent()` for [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), instead of use

- `JTextField.setBackground()`
- `JTextField.setForeground()`
- `JTextField.setFont()`
- `JTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT)`
- some hacks are possible by put there `Html` colored or special formatted text

EDIT

maybe this question is about

- filtering `KeyEvents` in the `Document / DocumentListener`

or

- `JFormattedTextField` with `Number Formatter`

Comment: I was about to up-vote that before I saw *"put there Html formatted text"* - would not look very good in a plain text component like `JTextField`.  ;)  Any chance of an edit, clarifying?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson done, but didn't claryfied your comment somehow, an answer could be for you in cases that you want to hightlighting possitions from --> to from Caret, InputMask, Document

Comment: I was simply referring to components like `JEditorPane` which support (HTML) formatted text..  I actually think the use-case needs a configured text field.  +1, for (now) the first 4 points.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson initially I want to answering [I retract everything](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10363871/714968), but I needed to check if sleeping before, hehehe [I have own FanClub too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129983/my-account-has-repeated-serial-upvotes-whats-going-on), in reversed form :-)

Comment: FanClub (dismissive) Peh!  [I have my own hate club](http://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson?tab=reputation).  It will be interesting to see if the script automatically detects & removes those 19 down-votes.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson you must ***** some real developer, there are a bunch of coders with real errors in her / his non_inflatable ego :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add a small `JLabel` to the front of the `JTextField`? The `JLabel` could contain the number, and because it isn't editable it will always be there no matter what the user changes in the `JTextField`. You could also format the `JLabel` to make it red by calling `setForeground(Color.RED);`. This might be a much simpler solution?

For example, instead of doing this...

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JTextField textfield = new JTextField("Hello");
panel.add(textfield,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You might do something like this...

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

JTextField textfield = new JTextField("Hello");
panel.add(textfield,BorderLayout.CENTER);

JLabel label = new JLabel("1.");
label.setForeground(Color.RED);
panel.add(label,BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Which adds a red `JLabel` to the left of the `JTextField`, and because you're using `BorderLayout` for the `JPanel` then it automatically makes the `JLabel` the smallest it can possibly be.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I mean that instead of adding a JTextField to your JPanel, you would actually add a JLabel and a JTextField. Please refer to my edited answer. If you can't get the JLabel to appear, you must be overwriting it with something else. For example, calling JPanel.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER) followed by JPanel.add(textfield,BorderLayout.CENTER) will overwrite the label and only show the textfield. You'd need to ensure they aren't overwriting each other by setting thel to different locations, as per my edited code. Hope this helps.